# A CakePHP query calls COUNT() twice for no apparent reason

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-model

*Note: I originally asked this question about an hour ago but only recently realized I had made a major copy and paste mistake. One so significant that it was easier to delete the old post and start over. Sorry about that.*

In the CakePHP framework, after I updated a Model, I dumped the SQL queries. `COUNT(*)` is called twice, for no apparent reason.

So I have two Models, `$Foo` and `$Bar`. For simplicity sake, I have *not* defined any `$belongsTo` or `$hasMany` relationships between them. The problem only involves $Foo, but just in case I've included $Bar's code as well.

```
$data = array(
    'something' => 12,
    'something_else' => $this->Bar->field('id', $conditions),
);

$this->Foo->id = $this->Foo->field($data);
$this->Foo->save($data);
```

I am getting the `$Bar.id` field according to a set of conditions (which aren't relevant here). I use that id to determine the `$data` that should INSERT or UPDATE into `$Foo`. If `$Foo` has an id that fulfills `$data`'s requirements that value will be returned; if not *false* will be returned. According to CakePHP's architecture, `save()` will UPDATE if there's a valid id; otherwise it will INSERT. I'm pretty sure I'm not doing anything unusual.

Here's what I see in the SQL dump:

```sql
SELECT `Foo`.`id` FROM `foos` AS `Foo` WHERE `something` = 12 AND `something_else` = 1 LIMIT 1
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `foos` AS `Foo` WHERE `Foo`.`id` = 1
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `foos` AS `Foo` WHERE `Foo`.`id` = 1
UPDATE `foos` SET `something` = 12, something_else` = 1 WHERE `foos`.`id` = 1'
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why `COUNT()` is needed at all, much less why it's called twice. Does anyone have an idea of what's going on? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't worked with CakePHP, but looking at the source code [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/5270721adee6aa4b2d07a61f589f729092ab9632/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php), you'll see in the field function that it calls the find method.

Therefore, this call

```
$data = array(
    'something' => 12,
    'something_else' => $this->Bar->field('id', $conditions),
);
```

Generates:

```
SELECT `Foo`.`id` FROM `foos` AS `Foo` WHERE `something` = 12 AND `something_else` = 1     LIMIT 1
```

Then the set field call

```
$this->Foo->id = $this->Foo->field($data);
```

generates this through the inner find function call:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `foos` AS `Foo` WHERE `Foo`.`id` = 1
```

The Save function also calls find to see if the record exists before saving, which generates the second call:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `foos` AS `Foo` WHERE `Foo`.`id` = 1
```

The final query is the obvious save itself.

Please look for yourself to verify I'm reading it correctly, but that's what it appears to do.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer. Thanks so much Rachael!

Comment: So... Is it just an intentional behaviour by CakePHP?

Comment: Alvaro, at the time of this post four years ago, it looked intentional though I haven't looked at the code since.  There could be an option to modify the behavior but that's outside my expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell you what's going on (as I don't think there's enough code), but can give you a workaround.

Use the "INSERT INTO table(id, field, field2) VALUES(id, value, value2) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field=value, field2=value2" syntax to do your query.

This lets SQL to the checking for duplicates, and will also illiminate those fractions of seconds between you checking of the row exists and trying to insert (just in case another process inserts after your check). For this, the field "id" must be either a primary key or a "unique" index so it knows to trigger the update.

Comment: I agree Robbie, and I already knew of the workaround. I was just trying to understand how CakePHP's wrappers work. Thanks.